# Pandas - Parsing datetime column from sqlite database

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm currently exploring the python library pandas with some hands-on data, where one of the columns contains a datetime object. However, when a table is parsed using the DataFrame method, the datetime objects in the date column are parsed to an initial value e.g. 1970-01-16 14:12:28.

If I for instance have a np.array with following content:

```
np.array(result, dtype=my_dtype) =
array([ (datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 8, 15, 10)),
dtype=[('Date', ('<M8[us]', {})), ('Forecasting', ('<M8[us]', {})),
```

when parsed, it will return following:

```
test = pandas.DataFrame(np.array(result, dtype=my_dtype))
test['Date'] =
1970-01-16 14:12:28.800000
```

and

```
test['Forecasting'] =
1970-01-16 14:11:57
```

Is this a bug, or what am I doing wrong?

FYI: pandas.**version** = 0.8.1, numpy.**version** = 1.6.2 and Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `panda`, but I suspect something is wrong with the `dtype` you're choosing for your fields. It looks like you're using `[us]`, that is, microseconds from the epoch (1970-01-01), when you probably should be using `days` from the epoch.

Another possibility is to use basic `datetime` objects in your `ndarray`, by using `dtype=object`.

Comment: Yes, it is probably that which causes incorrect parsing. I'm parsing the datetime with the np.datetime64 datatype, but how can I do this any different?

Comment: Check [this link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) for NumPy and datetime, in particular for setting your frequency. Note that while it works, it's still not considered as 100% foolproof. An alternative would be to make a `ndarray` of `datetime` objects by choosing `dtype=object`.

Comment: It actually works if I change the dtype to object instead. But I don't understand how I can change the datetime datatype by changing the epoch? (like datetime['D'])

Comment: `'<M8[D]'` in your first line ?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Tried `'<M8[D]'` and `'np.datetime64[D]'`.

Comment: Where was your `result` from? Is it a NumPy or panda problem ?

Comment: Well, it depends... It accepts the datatype and parses it as an day-epoch, but when I try to parse it with pd.DataFrame() method, it still parses the datetime-object as a [us]-datetime object.

Comment: Would you edit your answer so it includes the `dtype=object` suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. Reported here: http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2095